# Replicating a standalone HBase 0.2 deployment

Tags: java, replication, hbase

As far as I'm aware the current stable release of HBase, 0.2, does not support replication, although it is being built into the [next version](http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.89.20100726/replication.html).

How would you recommend replicating a standalone (non-distributed) deployment of HBase (0.2) ?

I want the secondary instance to be used as a working backup i.e. read-only. I can afford asynchronous backups with "eventual consistency", and a small amount of loss (the data is non-critical).

So far my only thought was to manually update the secondary instance, asynchronously, after writing to the primary instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HBase natively tolerates node failure/failover (assuming that you are running on HDFS), so it's not really necessary to maintain a replica like you would with a RDBMS.

What's wrong with just using HDFS replication?

EDIT: In this case, you would switch from standalone to distributed, and just have 2 nodes with a replication factor of 2.

Comment: Thanks. Does a replication factor of two mean the data is duplicated across both machines?

Comment: It does. For what it's worth, I think hadoop requires 3 machines in a cluster to survive the failure of 1.